# Verifying a call parameter via a callback in NSubstitute

Tags: c#, unit-testing, callback, mocking, nsubstitute

I have a failing test in NSubstitute because a parameter passed in to a substituted call does not match. Here is the relevant code that is being tested:

```
// Arrange
PermissionsProviderSub = Substitute.For<IPermissionsProvider>();
MenuDataProviderSub = Substitute.For<IMenuDataProvider>();
PermissionsProviderSub.GetPermissions(UserId).Returns(ExpectedUserPermissions);
MenuDataProviderSub.GetMenuData(ExpectedUserPermissions.AuthorisedPageIds).Returns(Arg.Any<IList<BusinessFocusArea>>());            
var sut = new MenuViewModelFactory(MenuDataProviderSub, PermissionsProviderSub);

// Act
var result = sut.Create();

// Assert
MenuDataProviderSub.Received().GetMenuData(ExpectedUserPermissions.AuthorisedPageIds);
```

The problem occurs in the `ExpectedUserPermissions.AuthorisedPageIds` property, which looks like this:

```
public IEnumerable<string> AuthorisedPageIds
{
    get
    {
        return ApplicationPagePermissions != null ? 
            ApplicationPagePermissions.Select(permissionSet => permissionSet.PageId) :
            Enumerable.Empty<string>();
    }
}
```

As you can see, there is a LINQ Select, which is extracting the `PageId` property from within the `ApplicationPagePermissions` collection and returning it as an `IEnumerable<string>`. Because the projection within that property creates a new object, the substitution does not match, as it sees the 2 objects as being different.

**Can I create a callback on the parameter passed in to `GetMenuData` so that I can examine the value of it?**

The documentation on [NSubstitute callbacks](http://nsubstitute.github.com/help/callbacks/) only talks about examining the return value from a call, rather than a parameter passed into the call.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Typical. As soon as I post to SO, the answer presents itself. Rather than expecting a specific object when creating the substitute call, I expect any instance of type `IEnumerable<string>` and create a callback when checking the `Received()` call that actually verifies the values. The substitute call becomes this:

```
MenuDataProviderSub.GetMenuData(Arg.Any<IEnumerable<string>>()).Returns(Arg.Any<IList<BusinessFocusArea>>());
```

The `Received()` check becomes this:

```
MenuDataProviderSub.Received().GetMenuData(Arg.Is<IEnumerable<string>>(a => VerifyPageIds(ExpectedUserPermissions.AuthorisedPageIds, a)));

private static bool VerifyPageIds(IEnumerable<string> expected, IEnumerable<string> actual)
{
    var expectedIds = expected.ToList();
    var actualIds = actual.ToList();
    return expectedIds.Count == actualIds.Count && expectedIds.All(actualIds.Contains);
}
```

Comment: Note [you may consider combining it with FluentAssertions as explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77954728/15488899), as that may get you a nicer syntax.