# NSubstitute - Check arguments passed to method

Tags: c#, mocking, nsubstitute

We are currently in the process of moving from RhinoMocks to NSubstitute.

I have a method that takes an object of type `DatabaseParams`. This class has the following structure (simplified):

```
public class DatabaseParams
  {
    public string StoredProcName { get; private set; }
    public SqlParameter[] Parameters { get; private set; }

    public DatabaseParams(string storeProcName, SqlParameter[] spParams)
    {
      StoredProcName = storeProcName;
      Parameters = spParams;
    }
  }
```

I have the following method I want to check the arguments being passed to it are correct:

```
public interface IHelper
{
Task<object> ExecuteScalarProcedureAsync(DatabaseParams data);
}
```

How do I test that an instance of `DatabaseParams` was passed into that method with the correct values?

I could do this in **RhinoMocks** with something like this:

```
helperMock.Expect(m => m.ExecuteScalarProcedureAsync(Arg<DatabaseHelperParameters>.Matches(
        p =>   p.StoredProcName == "up_Do_Something"
            && p.Parameters[0].ParameterName == "Param1"
            && p.Parameters[0].Value.ToString() == "Param1Value"
            && p.Parameters[1].ParameterName == "Param2"
            && p.Parameters[1].Value.ToString() == "Param2Value"
        ))).Return(Task.FromResult<DataSet>(null));
```

The `helperMock` is mocking the interface `IHelper` that contains the `ExecuteScalarProcedureAsync` method.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I've figured out the answer myself.

NSubstitute just needs to use the .Received() call and then when you specify your argument to the method. You can specify the argument matching as a predicate.

For example:

```
  helperMock.Received().ExecuteScalarProcedureAsync(Arg.Is<DatabaseParams>(
   p =>   p.StoredProcName == "up_Do_Something"
        && p.Parameters[0].ParameterName == "Param1"
        && p.Parameters[0].Value.ToString() == "Param1Value"
        && p.Parameters[1].ParameterName == "Param2"
        && p.Parameters[1].Value.ToString() == "Param2Value"));
```

Comment: For my use case, I had to make the call on my object with `ReceivedWithAnyArgs` rather than `Received`.

Answer (score 27):

There are two approaches that allow you to call assertions against specific properties, which give you better feedback on which properties of the argument object are incorrect.

## Do

An alternative is to use `Do` (see https://nsubstitute.github.io/help/actions-with-arguments/).  For example:

```
StoredProc sp = null; // Guessing the type here

// Setup Do to capture arg
helperMock.ExecuteScalarProcedureAsync(Arg.Do<DatabaseParams>(p => sp = p));

// Call method
helperMock.ExecuteScalarProcedureAsync(dbParams);

// NUnit assertions, but replace with whatever you want.
Assert.AreEqual("up_Do_Something", sp.StoredProcName);
Assert.AreEqual("Param1", p.Parameters[0].ParameterName);
Assert.AreEqual("Param1Value", p.Parameters[0].Value.ToString());
Assert.AreEqual("Param2", p.Parameters[1].ParameterName);
Assert.AreEqual("Param2Value", p.Parameters[1].Value.ToString());
```

## ReceivedCalls

The `ReceivedCalls` method can also be used, avoiding the need to have to call `Arg.Do` prior to calling the method under test.

```
// Call method
helperMock.ExecuteScalarProcedureAsync(dbParams);

var sp = helperMock.ReceivedCalls().ToList().GetArguments()[0];

// NUnit assertions, but replace with whatever you want.
Assert.AreEqual("up_Do_Something", sp.StoredProcName);
Assert.AreEqual("Param1", p.Parameters[0].ParameterName);
Assert.AreEqual("Param1Value", p.Parameters[0].Value.ToString());
Assert.AreEqual("Param2", p.Parameters[1].ParameterName);
Assert.AreEqual("Param2Value", p.Parameters[1].Value.ToString());
```

The `ReceivedCalls` method is [not listed in the official documentation](https://github.com/nsubstitute/NSubstitute/issues/528), but it does work in the above scenario.

Comment: Very nice solution! For me it did not work when setting it up like this. I had to first set up `helperMock.ExecuteScalarProcedureAsync(Arg.Do<DatabaseParams>(p => sp = p));` (that is, without the `Received()` part). Then, later on, when `ExecuteScalarProcedureAsync()` is called, `sp` will be set.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Maybe there's been a change in the API. I've been away from the .NET world for a bit, so good to get some clarification.

Comment: Take note that you have to Arrange the capturing of the variable BEFORE you Act in your test.  When you Assert, it will be there.

Answer (score 4):

A bit late for the party, but ran into the same need.
I am working with mockito in java, and they have an Argument capture helper that I like.
It is basically the same as @Castrohenge answer

So here is my NSubstitute implementation.

```
public interface IFoo
{
    void DoSomthing(string stringArg);
}
```

Argument capture class

```
public class ArgCapture<T>
{
    private List<T> m_arguments = new List<T>();

    public T capture()
    {
        T res = Arg.Is<T>(obj => add(obj)); // or use Arg.Compat.Is<T>(obj => add(obj)); for C#6 and lower
        return res;
    }

    public int Count
    {
        get { return m_arguments.Count; }
    }

    public T this[int index]
    {
        get { return m_arguments[index]; }
    }

    public List<T> Values {
        get { return new List<T>(m_arguments);}
    }

    private bool add(T obj)
    {
        m_arguments.Add(obj);
        return true;
    }
}
```

And the usage test case

```
    [Test]
    public void ArgCaptureTest()
    {
        IFoo foo1 = Substitute.For<IFoo>();
        ArgCapture<string> stringArgCapture = new ArgCapture<string>();
        foo1.DoSomthing("firstCall");
        foo1.DoSomthing("secondCall");
        foo1.Received(2).DoSomthing(stringArgCapture.capture());
        Assert.AreEqual(2,stringArgCapture.Count);
        Assert.AreEqual("firstCall",stringArgCapture[0]);
        Assert.AreEqual("secondCall", stringArgCapture[1]);
    }
```

Comment: This solution works really well and produces neat and flexible code.

Answer (score 0):

There is also an awesome project called [`FluentAssertionsBridge`](https://github.com/PapGroup/NSubstitute.FluentAssertionsBridge) that allows you to combine NSubtitute with [the awesome FluentAssertions](https://fluentassertions.com/), especially [their object graph comparisons/assertions](https://fluentassertions.com/objectgraphs/).

From the website example:

```
using PAP.NSubstitute.FluentAssertionsBridge;

// ...
var service = Substitute.For<IRegistrationService>();
var expected = new RegistrationModel(){ Username = "Admin", Password="123456" };

// ...

service.Received(1).Register(Verify.That<RegistrationModel>(a=> a.Should().BeEquivalentTo(expected)));
```

As such, your code would turn to:

For [mocking, you can me less strict and just mock all return values](https://nsubstitute.github.io/help/return-for-any-args/):

```cs
helperMock.ExecuteScalarProcedureAsync(default).ReturnsForAnyArgs(null));

// or, actually, in this case
helperMock.ExecuteScalarProcedureAsync(default).ReturnsNullForAnyArgs(null));
```

(`Task.FromResult` is BTW, IIRC; not needed. NSubstitute automatically wraps it in a task.)

```cs
// just build your expected model, as needed, properties you do not want to check, can be left out
const expectedParams = new DatabaseParams(...) { Parameters = ...}

helperMock.Received(1).ExecuteScalarProcedureAsync(Verify.That<DatabaseParams>(x => x.Should().BeEquivalentTo(expectedParams));
```

I guess this looks much cleaner.