# How to get the called parameters with NSubstitute? (or at least assert against their properties)

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, nsubstitute

**Context**

I would like to check if some parameter property value was the expected when my substite's method was called with a single parameter.

It would be the simplest to having the instance which was the parameter, then 
checking some of its properties against the expected.

I've checked the page http://nsubstitute.github.io/help/received-calls/ but I can not find neither how to get the actual parameter, neither such a check condition.

**Question**

```
var sut = new MyObject(myNSubstitue)
sut.Execute()
// Let suppose mySubstitute has an OperationX(MyClass parameter) method
// Now I would like to check OperationX was called, and called with
// a parameter which's parameter.MyPropery == "Hello"
```

Missed I something?

Comment: You may also ask yourself, why you want to do that. _NSubstitute_ has proper methods for `.Received` checking. And if you, as you say, just want to check some properties, you can do so. As the normal NSubstitute syntax get's convoluted quite fast, [you may consider combining it with FluentAssertions as explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77954728/15488899).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `Received()` assertion and [argument matching](http://nsubstitute.github.io/help/argument-matchers/) to check property of MyClass passed to OperationX:

```
mySubstitute.Received().OperationX(Arg.Is<MyClass>(mc => mc.MyProperty == "Hello"));
```

Comment: Many thanks. Obviously I took not enough time to review the argument match part of the doc, so this universal "is" with lambda did not come across.