# How do I unit test an async function with no return?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, xunit, nsubstitute

I am new to unit testing and I am trying to use NSubstitute and XUnit to write unit tests for my Add and Get functions from MongoDB. I am struggling trying to figure out how to test for the Add function which has no return and only does an InsertOneAsync of the document into the database.

This is my repository class that I am trying to test.

```
public class SampleRepository : ISampleRepository
{
    private readonly IMongoCollection<SampleSet> _sampleSetCollection;

    public SamplesRepository(IMongoCollection<SampleSet> sampleSetCollection)
    {
        _sampleSetCollection = sampleSetCollection;
    }

    public async Task<SampleSet?> GetSampleSetAsync(string sampleType)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(sampleType))
        {
            return null;
        }

        var filter = Builders<SampleSet>.Filter.Eq(nameof(SampleSet.SampleType), sampleType);
        return await _sampleSetCollection
            .Find(filter)
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
    }

    public async Task AddSampleSetAsync(SampleSet sampleSet)
    {
        await _sampleSetCollection.InsertOneAsync(sampleSet);
    }
}
```

}

And this is the unit tests where I am stuck at

```
public class SamplesRepositoriesTests
{
    private readonly IMongoCollection<SampleSet> _mongoCollection = Substitute.For<IMongoCollection<SampleSet>>();
    private ISamplesRepository _samplesRepository;

    public SamplesRepositoriesTests()
    {
        var services = new ServiceCollection();
        services.AddTransient(sp => _mongoCollection);

        var provider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
        _mongoCollection = provider.GetRequiredService<IMongoCollection<SampleSet>>();
    }
      
  public async Task AddSampleSetAsync_ValidSampleSet()
 {
var samples = new List<Sample> { new Sample("test", "{\"test\":\"test\"}") };
var expected = new SampleSet("test", samples, "test", DateTime.UtcNow);  _mongoCollection.InsertOneAsync(expected).Returns(Task.CompletedTask);
        var samplesRepository = new SamplesRepository(_mongoCollection);

        await samplesRepository.AddSampleSetAsync(expected);

        Assert.Equal(_mongoCollection.InsertOneAsync(expected).Returns(Task.CompletedTask), await samplesRepository.AddSampleSetAsync(expected));
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task AddSampleSetAsync_InValidSampleSet()
    {
        var samples = new List<Sample> { };
        var testSampleSet = new SampleSet("test", samples, "test", DateTime.UtcNow);

        _samplerulesRepository = new SamplesRepository(_mongoCollection);

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Are you trying to write a _unit_ test or an _integration_ test? As _unit_ test, this does not make sense to me. _What_ do you want to test here? MongoDB?

Comment: It doesn't matter how you test it. It's a waste of time. `AddSampleSetAsync` is only calling a method on your Substitute, so none of your code is actually being tested. Only test your own code in unit tests, otherwise do an integration test.

Comment: I guess I want to test that if I am inserting a valid sampleset, that the AddSampleSetAsync would pass. I want to verify that the InsertOneAsync was successful. Would a unit test in this case not be the right kind of test? Is there a way to unit test the insertion into the mongo database?

Comment: You are mocking the db, so you are not testing the db. If you did, it would be an integration test and you'd have to verify that the inserted data is present in the _actual_ database. _"if I am inserting a valid sampleset, that the AddSampleSetAsync would pass"_ - It is not the business of an insert to verify validity of an entity. That should have been checked _before_ you even try to insert it. But anyway, granted your insert _does_ check vailidity, then I guess it does report failure by throwing. So you can only test for it to "not throw" on a valid entry and throw on invalid ones.

Answer (score 2):

as others mentioned already, it's not the task of your unit-test to check if Mongo works as it is supposed to work. There's no point in testing the `InsertOneAsync`-function yourself, as Mongo already does this within their own tests (hopefully). Only test *your* code. As you're only executing a single statement, you could check if that exact statement *has been called*, which is slightly different to checking if that statement *does what it should do*.

You can use the `Recieved`-call on your mock to check if a function with a set of args has been called:

```
_sampleSetCollection = Substitite.For<IMongoCollection<SampleSet>>();
...
await _sampleSetCollection.Recieved().InsertOneAsync(sampleSet);
```

So your test would be this:

```
public async Task AddSampleSetAsync_ValidSampleSet()
{
    // arrange
    var samples = new List<Sample> { new Sample("test", "{\"test\":\"test\"}") };
    var sampleSet = new SampleSet("test", samples, "test", DateTime.UtcNow);  

    var coll = Substitute.For<IMongoCollection<SampleSet>>();
    var samplesRepository = new SamplesRepository(coll);

    // act
    await samplesRepository.AddSampleSetAsync(sampleSet);

    // assert
    coll.Recieved().InsertOneAsync(sampleSet);
}
```

Comment: That worked for me, I really appreciate all the help from everyone. I guess I was very paranoid that I had to verify everything and not narrowing it down on just testing what I had control of which was if the statement was called instead.

Comment: One question which I was not sure about if I need to make a new post was for the GetSampleAsync which I have two unit tests written but dont work which tests for a valid Sample an Invalid Sample. Would you know why when I am trying to test the return null, it gives me Actual: Task<SampleSet> { Status = RanToCompletion }

Comment: @ChAnViNi a function that returns a task allways returns a task, even if you "return null".  So `null` is effectivly wrapped into a (completed) task. When you were to `await` that task, its result was `null`, though. See this excellent answer for a deeper view: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45347160/is-it-better-to-return-an-empty-task-or-null-c-sharp

Comment: Regarding if there is a point in testing `InsertOneAsync`. I would agree but with one caveat. It can be useful to unit test third party libraries to ensure you are using it correctly. The library may work exactly as *specified* and/or *indended*, but not as you *expect*. For complex libraries it can be easier to write tests than trying to figure out the behavior from reading the sometimes poor documentation.

Answer (score 1):

- Replace mock with actual repository instance, maybe create in-memory version of it.
- After calling insert, verify that data exists by querying it from repository.

However, I don't think its necessary to unit test repository at all. Basically it doesn't make any sense to do that.

Instead, you might want to test the service, which uses your repository.
In order to test that calling fictional **Add** method of the service inserts data passed, you will need to use some sort of in-memory repository.
So logic of your test would be:

1. create a service (not the mock)
2. inject your in-memory repository/dbcontext (not the mock)
3. test/assert that calling an Add method of your service saves the entity in the context/collection/whatever

Comment: Hi! So I actually have a service which I have been able to successfully unit test that. I guess I was not sure if there was a way to be unit testing the repository layer

Comment: you can do couple of things
1. verify that repository's insert method is called via NSubstitutes Received method. 2. verify repository received a correct object  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31316550/nsubstitute-check-arguments-passed-to-method

Comment: So I was trying to use the Received method like this `samplesRepository.Received().AddSampleSetAsync(Arg.Is<SampleSet>(p => p.SampleType == "test"));`

Comment: Any issues with that?

Comment: So the issue I am getting is `NSubstitute extension methods like .Received() can only be called on objects created using Substitute.For<T>() and related methods` Which I understand that I didn't create using the Substitute.For but should I substitute just like how I did for the _mongoCollection?

Comment: Yes, exactly. When you test a service, you instantiate it with a substitute of your repository. Then you verify that repository received a call to InsertOneAsync method. Optionally you can also verify parameters are correct like you did above.

Comment: What would be the syntax for verifying the InsertOneAsync method? I have my interface for the samplesRepository like this `public interface ISamplesRepository
{
    Task<SampleSet?> GetSampleSetAsync(string sampleType);
    Task AddSampleSetAsync(SampleSet sampleSet);
}`  I want created the Substitute.For like `private ISamplesRepository _samplesRepository = Substitute.For<ISamplesRepository>();` The line I wrote for the Received() still gave me back the error I had above

Comment: try Received(1)

Comment: Same issue unfortunately. I am wondering if it has to do with my Substitute.For that I am doing wrong